# Microsoft Visio 2010 Zoom to 100% using keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-visio-2010

I'm using the mouse to change zoom level to 100% and this annoys me because I use it a lot. 
Using zoom <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and zooming with mouse (left click or wheel) almost never result in exactly 100% but rather 105%.

Does anyone have a keyboard shortcut or know how to create one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odd thing: I can't get 100%. Trying to set it to 100% (even in the `Percentage:` box) results in 106% for me. So I'll assume 106% == 100%.

There's some keyboard shortcuts listed in the help document [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-visio-2010-HP010357062.aspx):

Zoom in: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd>
Zoom out: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd>
Fit to window: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>

They didn't document a zoom to 100% (actual size).

Noticing that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> turns my cursor into a magnifying glass, I started hitting random keys.

Zoom to 106% (100%? See below.): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>

---

Second odd thing: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> do absolutely nothing for me. In Firefox they zoom, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> being restore to normal size, but they do nothing for me in Visio 2010.

---

[Apparently](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/visiogeneral/thread/2f7292ba-f670-4df8-9bdc-75b1c49f3825) the 106% thing is a known bug related to the metric drawing templates. There's a workaround at that link, but you should be fine if you're using US templates.

Comment: [CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[I] did the trick, thanks :). btw how do you get the images for keys you use in your answer?

Comment: @rdkleine Click the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/425158/edit) button under my answer and you can see the source - including the keys. Specifically, I'm using the [`<kbd>` tag](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4043/nicer-kbd-style).